# Wrongly semi transparent views in iPhone objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, view, transparency

I'm working on an iPhone game written in Objective C (which I'm new to). The problem is
that the views which are used to draw the sprites on screen are semi transparent. I have set
the alpha to 1.0 and the opacity to True. I have also used NSLog to confirm that the views' alphas are 1.0. I was using [self.view insertSubview:myView]; to add a view to be drawn but also tried [self.view insertSubview:myView aboveSubview:myOtherView]; just in case they were drawing onto each other.

I have tried searching google but can't seem to articulate a query which helps. I'm using OS 3.0. and I haven't included all the code because there is a lot of it. ANY help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the view to which you are referring a subview to another view that has an alpha set to a value less than 1.0?  Alphas propagate down the the view hierarchy.

Comment: That was it, When the revolution comes Austrailia shall be yours.

Comment: I hereby vow that Australia will prosper under my benevolent reign!

Back to the original topic -- I just did a quick experiment -- the alpha continues to propagate through the view hierarchy *even* if you set the inner view's opaque = YES.  Sad.  Would be nice to be able to "restart" the alpha.  Probably very hard for Apple to implement though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are getting semi-transparent views, but I would suggest not using UIViews for an iPhone game. Try a more game-oriented system like cocos2d. http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/